# Misplace \omit in \multicolumn alias definition

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm attempting to make my syntax cleaner and more readable (to me) by making aliases for some commands. One is the `\mC` command, which produces a `multicolumn` with removed left and right padding. When invoking the command, I get a `misplaced \omit` error. Any ideas?

PS: is there a non-risky way to redefine tabular to default to `@{}` at the ends of the tabular column specification (but not in between...)?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mC}{m O{c} m}{% multicolumn cell
    \multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}{#3}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\lbC}{O{t} O{l} m}{% line-break cell
    \makecell[{#1}{#2}]{#3}%
}%


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
        \lbC[b][l]{L1\\L2} & a & b\\
        \mC{2}[l]{Multi col}  & 3 \\ % causes misplaces \omit
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Multi col}  & 3 \\  % works fine
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `\mC` command has to expand to `\multicolumn` rather directly, without parsing for optional arguments. A plain `\newcommand` with three mandatory arguments works.

You can define your `mytabular` such that it always adds `@{}` at the beginning and at the end, but you will still have to remember it when adding `\multicolumn` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mC[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}{#3}}%
\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}%
}{%
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mytabular}{lll}
      \mC{2}{l}{Multirow}  & 3 \\
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Multirow}  & 3 \\
    \end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there some sort of trickery required if I want to define `\mC` with xparse? I prefer its syntax and find it easier to modify and adapt.

Comment: I now see that I can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`